I can't find a nice literal translation for "Stella caeli exstirpavit"
It is a famous Catholic prayer:

Stella caeli exstirpavit 
Quae lactavit Dominum 
Mortis pestem quam plantavit 
Primus parens hominum.

The first line just doesn't make sense to me and apparently neither to everyone else.
Stella is a feminine word, it means star and it is first declension.
caeli is on the genitive and exstirpavit is a verb of first conjugation that means to extirpate (third person singular perfect indicative).
I can't make sense of this sentence unless the verb exstirpare is like utor and admits object on the ablative, in this unlike case I'd like to know somewhere where I can check the verbal agreement with objects in latin.

Could the object of exstirpavit be pestem? "The star of heaven uprooted the plague of death." What's strange to me is the insertion of quae lactavit Dominum ("who suckled the Lord") where you'd expect the object of exstirpavit to go.

It seems to me that the core sentence is Stella exstirpavit pestem.
Both the subject and the object get a genitive attribute (caeli, mortis) and a relative clause (quae…, quam…).
I don't see why stella caeli couldn't be simply "star of/in the sky".
The verb exstirpare seems to be indeed transitive, given the examples I see in L&S.

You beat me by a few minutes. What surprised me was lactare being transitive and then meaning more or less the opposite of what it means in Romulus lactans (cf. Cic. Cat. 3, 19).

@SebastianKoppehel I was surprised by looking at the L&S entry for it. Apparently it's used both ways as "to give/take milk". +1 to your more thorough answer!

Start out with a line-by-line (lineatim?) translation:

The star of heaven eradicated
That breastfed the Lord
The sickness of death, which planted
First the parent of men.

Rearranging this a bit:

The star of heaven, which breastfed the Lord, eradicated the sickness of death, which had been planted first by the progenitor of all humans.

I'm no theologian, but I believe it's a safe bet that this song refers to the Virgin Mary, because (a) who else could claim to have given the Lord the breast, and (b) Catholic lyrics have a greater-than-average chance of being about her. It also becomes even clearer at the end of the song:

Audi nos Domina,
Nam Filius tuus nihil negans
Te honorat.
Salva nos Iesu,
Pro quibus Virgo mater te orat.

Perhaps less obvious, the progenitor of all men cannot be Eve, as he is clearly masculine in the Latin. I guess this refers to Adam then, but as I said, I am no theologian.

As someone with quite a few years of Catholic theology studies finished, I confirm the Mary and Adam hypotheses.
